# ValueError: X has 1 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 416809 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am making a simple program that given a prompt, will predict the emotions associated. I have a dataset in the form of a CSV file with 416809 items containing examples like so:

| id | text | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | i just feel really helpless and heavy hearted | 4 |
| 1 | ive enjoyed being able to slouch about relax and unwind and frankly needed it after those last few weeks around the end of uni and the expo i have lately started to find myself feeling a bit listless which is never really a good thing | 0 |

(Label is a number from 0-5 which corresponds with one of six emotions)

My code is as follows:

```py
print("Loading modules...")
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

print("Loading data...")
data = pd.read_csv('data/emotions.csv') #load dataset to data variable
X = data["text"] #set X value to a table of all specified columns
y = data["label"] #set y value to the column of answers

le = LabelEncoder() #encode labels
le.fit(y)
encoded_y = le.transform(y)
le.fit(X)
encoded_X = le.transform(X)

print("Training model...")
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit([encoded_X],[encoded_y]) #train the model
prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")

encoded_prompt = le.transform([prompt])

predictions = model.predict([encoded_prompt]) #predict
```

I get an error in the last line:

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 416809 features as input.
```

What I'm expecting is  for the `predictions` variable to be a number or a list containing a single number from 0-5 and for it to print the last line in the code.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html); you will see that to train/fit your model you will require an X of shape (n_samples, n_features), so I would change the fit to the next line (reshaping the X to at least one feature):

```
model.fit(encoded_X.reshape(-1, 1),encoded_y)
```

Apart from that, LabelEncoder is used typically to encode the target (y) if you need normalize them or transform non-numerical labels. As your target is already numeric, probably you don't need to encode it.

In addition, it is not a good practice to use the LabelEncoder with your categorical features. If you use your code as it is, it is not actually analyzing the text but giving to each unique value one numeric identifier, so, the prompt you type must be one chosen from the 416809 samples.

If what you are trying to do is to know the basics on sentiment analysis by using Scikit-learn, I would start with the following links:

Working with text data: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

This one looks also interesting:
https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-sentiment-analysis-with-scikit-learn/